# How to test a non-view function in a Flask app factory?

Tags: flask, pytest

I'm using the factory pattern in Flask. This is a simplified version of my code:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.before_request
    def update_last_seen():
        if current_user.is_authenticated:
            current_user.update(last_seen=arrow.utcnow().datetime)

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def home():
         return render_template("home.html")

    return app
```

I'm using `pytest-flask` and I would like to be able to write a test for the `update_last_seen` function.

How can I access that function? I can't find it in client.application (`client` being a fixture auto-used through pytest-flask), nor in my `app` fixture that I set through `conftest.py` like so:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    os.environ["FLASK_ENV"] = "test"
    os.environ["MONGO_DB"] = "test"
    os.environ["MONGO_URI"] = 'mongomock://localhost'

    app = create_app()
    app.config['ENV'] = 'test'
    app.config['DEBUG'] = True
    app.config['TESTING'] = True

    app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False   

    return app
```

So when I run this test:

```
def test_previous_visit_is_stored_in_session(app, client):
    app.update_last_seen()
```

The error I get is:

```
    def test_previous_visit_is_stored_in_session(app, client):
>       app.update_last_seen()
E       AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'update_last_seen'
```

I've been looking through `app.before_request_funcs` too, but to no avail unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#other-testing-tricks), you can manually run the pre-processing of a request.

```
initial_last_seen = current_user.last_seen

with app.test_request_context('/'):
    app.preprocess_request()

    assert current_user.last_seen != initial_last_seen # ...for example
```